# Problem with \usepackage {hyperref}

Tags: errors, hyperref, urls

```
\documentclass [12pt,a4paper] {article}
\usepackage {geometry}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage {hyperref}
%
\begin {document}
bapi

\par

\begin {eqnarray}
\frac{dy}{dt} &=& -t \\
%
\frac{dx}{dt} &=& 1
%
\end {eqnarray}

\end {document}
```

To run the LaTeX file `abc.tex`, I use the command `latex abc.tex`.
Then an error message will occur:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `url.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed, or enter new name.
(Default extension: sty) Enter file name:
```

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` and the version of the TeX compiler in
my computer is `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)`.

Without `\usepackage{hyperref}`, there is no error message and the `.tex` file run smoothly.

What is the problem with `\usepackage{hyperref}`?

Comment: Which command did you run to build the file? When I run `latex -output-format pdf abc.tex` it compiles just fine.

Comment: And which error message does occur when you run pdftex?

Comment: It is well known that `eqnarray` doesn't work with `hyperref`; on the other hand, `eqnarray` should not be used, see [`eqnarray` vs `align`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196)

Comment: The error message is -------------- ! LaTeX Error: File `url.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:

Comment: while i use \usepackage{graphicx} , the file compile and run smoothly. But while use \usepackage {hyperref} , then error occurs @barbara beeton

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: `url.sty` is part of all the major tex distributions, if for some reason you really do not have it, just update your tex installation with your package manager and install it.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to update my latex, so that it runs without error ? I want to know the particular process, as you told about package manager . Please help @David Carlisle

Comment: I understand, what do you want to say, as I cannot use any \ref command for describing the process. But, I only want to know that why the code shows error only by using \usepackage {hyperref}. Thats all. @MartinSchröder

Comment: It's hard to know why you don't have url already (you could just copy it from ctan and put it in the same directory as your document) to do a proper install I would guess the debian  setup is managed by apt-get rather than the usual tlmgr from texlive but I do not know the details. just saving url.sty from here is probably simplest https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/url/

Comment: Any updates? Do you have this problem with up-to-day software and packages?

Answer (score 1):

Many packages rely on other packages for their work. For example,
package loads the following packages directly or indirectly:

- `keyval`
- `graphics`

  - `trig`

Furthermore, the configuration file `graphics.cfg` can load further packages, e.g. (without duplicates):

- `pdftexcmds`

  - `infwarerr`
  - `ltxcmds`
  - `ifpdf`
- `epstopdf-base`

  - `grfext`
  - `kvoptions`

    - `kvsetkeys`

      - `etexcmds`

Also, `hyperref` loads many packages, one of them is `url`. If the package is not installed, you get the error message and the macro `\url` will not work.

Solution:

Install the package with the means of your TeX distribution. Packages that are not provided by the TeX distribution (very unlikely in case of package `url`) can often be found on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/).

---

BTW, environment `eqnarray` is commonly considered as deprecated. Package `amsmath` provides much better and powerful environments for vertical equation alignments. See "[eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/16967)" for more details.